# This error where add frappe erpnext new-site

Tags: python-3.x, erpnext, frappe

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/utils/bench_helper.py", line 104, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/utils/bench_helper.py", line 19, in main
    click.Group(commands=commands)(prog_name='bench')
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/commands/site.py", line 38, in new_site
    _new_site(db_name, site, mariadb_root_username=mariadb_root_username,
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/installer.py", line 61, in _new_site
    install_db(
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/installer.py", line 108, in install_db
    setup_database(force, source_sql, verbose, no_mariadb_socket)
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/database/__init__.py", line 16, in setup_database
    return frappe.database.mariadb.setup_db.setup_database(force, source_sql, verbose, no_mariadb_socket=no_mariadb_socket)
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/database/mariadb/setup_db.py", line 39, in setup_database
    if force or (db_name not in dbman.get_database_list()):
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/database/db_manager.py", line 60, in get_database_list
    return [d[0] for d in self.db.sql("SHOW DATABASES")]
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/database/database.py", line 123, in sql
    self.connect()
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/database/database.py", line 75, in connect
    self._conn = self.get_connection()
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/database/mariadb/database.py", line 74, in get_connection
    conn = pymysql.connect(
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 633, in connect
    self._request_authentication()
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 907, in _request_authentication
    auth_packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "/home/osamagoda/frappe-bench/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'")
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens when frappe is not able to access database.

Check if the database is up & running. If it is up, check if the credentials are correct and if user has correct access by connecting to database directly.

You can also pass `--verbose` flag to see detailed logs for the command.

```
bench new-site --verbose test_site
```